# Benaloh cryptosystem

Tags: public-key

I was reading this article on Wikipedia, but I don't seem to understand how this holds: $u^\phi \equiv u^0 \mod n$. Can someone explain it to me? Thank you.

> #### Key Generation
>
> Given block size $r$, a public/private key pair is generated as follows:
>
> 1. Choose large primes $p$ and $q$ such that $r \vert (p-1)$,
>    $\operatorname{gcd}(r, (p-1)/r)=1$, and $\operatorname{gcd}(r,
>     (q-1))=1$.
> 2. Set $n=pq$, $\phi=(p-1)(q-1)$.
> 3. Choose $y \in \mathbb{Z}^*_n$ such that $y^{\phi/r} \not \equiv 1     \mod n$.
>
> **Note:** If $r$ is composite, it was pointed out by Fousse et al. in 2011\cite{ACRYPT} that the above conditions (i.e., those stated in the original paper) are insufficient to guarantee correct decryption, i.e., to guarantee that $D(E(m)) = m$ in all cases (as should be the case). To address this, the authors propose the following check: let $r=p_1p_2\dots p_k$ be the prime factorization of $r$. Choose $y \in \mathbb{Z}^*_n$ such that for each factor $p_i$, it is the case that $y^{\phi/p_i}\ne 1\mod n$.
>
> 4. Set $x=y^{\phi/r}\mod n$.
>
> The public key is then $y,n$, and the private key is $\phi,x$.
>
> #### Message Encryption
>
> To encrypt message $m\in\mathbb{Z}_r$:
>
> 1. Choose a random $u \in \mathbb{Z}^*_n$.
> 2. Set $E_r(m) = y^m u^r \mod n$.
>
> #### Message Decryption
>
> To decrypt a ciphertext $c\in\mathbb{Z}^*_n$:
>
> 1. Compute $a=c^{\phi/r}\mod n$.
> 2. Output $m=\log_x(a)$, i.e., find $m$ such that $x^m\equiv a \mod n$.
>
> To understand decryption, first notice that for any $m\in\mathbb{Z}_r$
> and $u\in\mathbb{Z}^*_n$ we have:
>
> $a = (c)^{\phi/r} \equiv (y^m u^r)^{\phi/r} \equiv (y^{m})^{\phi/r}(u^r)^{\phi/r} \equiv (y^{\phi/r})^m(u)^{\phi} \equiv (x)^m (u)^0 \equiv x^m \mod n$
>
> To recover $m$ from $a$, we take the discrete log of $a$ base $x$. If
> $r$ is small, we can recover $m$ by an exhaustive search, i.e.
> checking if $x^i\equiv a \mod n$ for all $0\dots (r-1)$. For larger
> values of $r$, the Baby-step giant-step algorithm can be used to
> recover $m$ in $O(\sqrt{r})$ time and space.

Comment: This is [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) (note that $u$ is coprime to $n$).

Comment: Thanks, I just remembered that $Z_n^*$ are the integers from $1$ to $n-1$ that are coprime to $n$.